# How to keep appending data from database as you retrieve, on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

Whenever I enter an id number in text box and click scan button, i get data from database and it is displayed below the text box in a predefined format. Now when i enter another id and hit scan, the new data thus retreived replaces the older one. I want it to be displayed below the already existing data on the page.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title> ShopNGo </title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

        </head>
    <body>
                <header id="header">
                        <div class="container">
                                <form name="products" method="POST">
                                        <br><br>
                            <button type="submit" name="scan" id="scan"> <h1> SCAN! </h1> </button>
                                        <br><br><br>
                                        <input type="text" name="id">
                        </form>
                        </div>
                </header>
                <div class="main">
            <table border="0">
<?php
                      if (isset($_POST["scan"])) {

                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "#";
                    $password = "#";
                    $dbname = "#";

                    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection Failed:" . mysqli_connect_error());
                                $query = "SELECT name, price, img FROM product WHERE id = $_POST[id]";
                                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                    {
                                            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                            {
                        echo "<tr> <table border='0'> <tr>";
                        echo "<img src='$row[img]'>";
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo $row["name"];
                        echo "<br>";
                        echo $row["price"];
                        echo "</tr> </table> </tr>";
                                            }
                    }
                                    mysqli_close($conn); }
            ?> 
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

please help me !!

also it would be a great help if u can suggest some improvements in the existing code other than what i asked for... Thank you so much !!

Comment: use Ajax to get data and append it to the existing data.

Comment: You're probably looking for `createElement()` and `appendChild()` rather than simply `echo`ing the contents to the page. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193133/php-appending-adding-html-content-to-exsisting-element-by-id) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

use ajax to post your id to another php script that checks id for data, put the html into a string variable and then echo it at the end. You can use the ajax success callback to append the data

```
     $.ajax({
type: "POST",
  url: url,
data: id,
success: function(data){
   $('#targetDiv').append(data);
     }
});
```

php script:

```
    $query = "SELECT name, price, img FROM product WHERE id = $_POST[id]";
                            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                {
                                        while($row = 
    mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                                        {
                    $element = "<tr> <table border='0'> <tr>";
                    $element .= "<img src='$row[img]'>";
                     $element .= "<br>";
                     $element .=$row["name"];
                     $element .= "<br>";
                     $element .= $row["price"];
                     $element .= "</tr> </table> </tr>";
                                        }
                }


          echo $element;
```