# How to PHP appendChild in an ID?

Tags: php, append, appendchild

I'm trying to append an associative array in my page. I searched a lot in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193133/php-appending-adding-html-content-to-exsisting-element-by-id) but when I try their answers it copies my page as many times as there are values.

Here is my code :

```
$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT nom FROM `scores`');

while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    foreach($donnees as $clef => $valeur){

        $html = file_get_contents('tableau.php');
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadHTML($html);
        $descBox = $doc->getElementById('noms');
        $appended = $doc->createElement('li', $valeur);
        $descBox->appendChild($appended);
        echo $doc->saveHTML();

    }
};
```

How can I do this without my page being multiplied ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must make loop only at part where `li` is created and appended:

```
$html = file_get_contents('tableau.php');
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$descBox = $doc->getElementById('noms');

$reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT nom FROM `scores`');
while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    foreach($donnees as $clef => $valeur){
        $appended = $doc->createElement('li', $valeur);
        $descBox->appendChild($appended);

    }
}

echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok With the help of Pavel Musil I found an answer to my multi appearing page :

I have seperated my page in 3 files :

The first one is just :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="fr">
 <?php
  include("scores.php");
 ?>
</html>
```

The second one is the PHP code :

```html
 <?php
  try {
   $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=scores','root','');
  }
  catch(Exception $e){
   die('erreur :'.$e->getMessage());
  };

  $bdd->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
  $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT nom FROM `scores`');
  $html = file_get_contents('tableauHtml.html');
  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  $doc->loadHTML($html);
  $descBox = $doc->getElementById('noms');

  $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT nom FROM `scores`');
  while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
      foreach($donnees as $clef => $valeur){
          $appended = $doc->createElement('li', $valeur);
          $descBox->appendChild($appended);
      }
  };

  echo $doc->saveHTML();
 ?>
```

And the last one is the HTML I want to insert my LI :

```html
 <head>
    ...
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id='all'>
   <h1>Ze Kouiz</h1>
   <div id="noms">

   </div>
      ...
 </body>
```

And it works !